# Does 'I have a crush on you' always imply romantic emotion?

Tags: meaning-in-context

English is not my native language, but I want to know if "I’ve always had a bit of a crush on you" always implies romantic emotion. Is it something friends may say to each other?

Answer (score 2):

According to Dictionary.com(http://www.dictionary.com/browse/have-a-crush-on-someone), *to have a crush on someone* specifically refers to a romantic love for someone. Though the feelings implied may not be as much strong as those implied by the word *love*, but it generally is a term of endearment.

Comment: Though the term may be used figuratively, where someone is described as having a "crush" on fancy sports cars or some such.

Comment: Just in case, I would be very careful of using it in a non-romantic context.